# Append and modify .bash_profile with Python

Tags: python, replace

I have to modify the .bash_profile for a user to include the openssl installation.

I need to modify this (or something similar):
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`
`export PATH`
to:
`PATH=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2g/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin/`
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2g/lib`
`export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

I made this code to replace:

```
def replace_file(original,new,file_name):
    for line in fileinput.input(file_name, inplace=True):
        print(line.replace(original, new).rstrip('\n'), )
    return
```

The code works, the only problem is that it will replace a complete phrase. I don't know what I have after PATH=.
Do you have any idea to make the replace?
Thanks

Comment: why don't you add at the end of the file instead of replacing a line in the middle?

Comment: Because I will be doing 2 different export PATH. I don't know what the PATH variable.

Comment: "Because I will be doing 2 different export PATH" what is the problem with that?

Comment: I guess it shouldn't be a problem. I will have to do PATH=$PATH:<openssl>.
Its not going to be a pretty code, but it will work.

Comment: it is actually recommend, from what I understand. each modification of the PATH adds a single entity, so you can easily remove it, and group the exports related to a given function.